# How to match and remove whole lines from a file in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two files:

1. Phrases.txt
2. Phrases-to-exclude.txt

Both files has a phrase on each line like this:

```
some phrase 1
some phrase 2
some phrase 3
```

Is there a way I can remove all the lines that are in the "Phrases to exclude" file from the main "Phrases" file?

The phrases are exact -- so only the entire line needs to be matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
phrases = File.read('Phrases.txt').lines
exclude = File.read('Phrases-to-exclude.txt').lines

File.write('Result.txt', (phrases - exclude).join)
```

Comment: Each line is a phrase, so that will work in this case.

Comment: Thats what I wanted -- each line to be an exact match (not substring).

Comment: @user3188544 Good, you should also mention it in the question itself for clarity to readers.

Comment: It's clarified in the comments ;)

Comment: @ArupRakshit Sorry about that -- I updated the question. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below also :

```
data_from_main_file = File.readlines('Phrases.txt')
data_to_exclude = File.readlines('Phrases-to-exclude.txt')
File.write('output.txt', (data_from_main_file - data_to_exclude).join)
```